# dimension of a complex vector space of the form $ S:=\{cw_k+\overline cw_{-k}\mid \langle c,k\rangle=0\}. $

Tags: linear-algebra

> For any two vectors $v,w\in\mathbb{C}^n$, define
>   $$
> vw=(v_1w_1,\cdots, v_nw_n),\quad \langle v,w\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n v_iw_i.\tag{*}
> $$
>   Note the absence of complex conjugate in $(*)$.
>
> For $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n\setminus\{0\}$, define the function $w_k:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ with 
>   $$
> w_k(x)=e^{2\pi i\langle k,x\rangle}.
> $$
>   Fix $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n\setminus\{0\}$. Consider the following function space over $\mathbb{C}$:
>   $$
> S:=\{cw_k(x)+\overline cw_{-k}(x)\mid \langle c,k\rangle=0,c\in\mathbb{C}^n\}. 
> $$

**Question**:
What is the dimension of $S$?

---

The answer should be $2(n-1)$ if I'm not wrong, according to the monograph I'm reading. But I don't see why. Something related can be worked out is that the solution space of $\langle c,k\rangle=0$ is of dimension $(n-1)$. I don't see how to get the $2$ there.

---

[**Motivation**]

I came up with the question above when I read an argument about the eigenvalues of Stokes operators. The result above is used to prove the asymptotic behavior of the eigenvalues of the Stokes operator in the periodic case.

Comment: The dimension of the function space as a ***real*** vector space of function ? the dimension of $\{c  w_k(.) \}$ is then $n$ as a complex vector space, i.e. $2n$ as a real vector space, and the dimension of $\{2Re(c  w_k(.) )\}$ is $2n-1$ as a real vector space

Answer (score 0):

$S$ should have the same dimension as 
$$
S'=\{cx+\overline{c}x^2\mid \langle c,k\rangle=0,c\in\mathbb{C}^n\},
$$
which has dimension $n-1$ as a *complex* vector space. The number $2(n-1)$ might be due to considering $S'$ as a *real* vector space.